# Cannot run tests using Protractor and Saucelabs

Tags: protractor

I'm trying to run my e-2-e tests using protractor and saucelabs.  When I run protractor I see the following output:

> protractor conf.js
>
> [15:56:40] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
>
> [15:56:40] I/sauce - Using SauceLabs selenium server at
>   https://ondemand.saucelabs.com:80

[image]

Nothing happens at this point and no test results are showing in my Saucelabs dashboard.

Here is my Protractor config file:

```
 exports.config = {
      framework: 'jasmine',
      sauceUser: 'username',
      sauceKey: 'key',
      sauceSeleniumAddress: 'ondemand.saucelabs.com:80', 
      specs: ['signup-specs.js', 'smoke-specs.js', 'schedule-specs.js'],
      jasmineNodeOpts: {
         showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.
         isVerbose: true,
         includeStackTrace: true
      },
      params: {
         url: ''
      },
      onPrepare: function () {
         browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
      }
 };
```

I can run my test locally using my local selenium server, but I can't get the tests to run in saucelabs.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I haven't installed anything specific to saucelabs at this point, I just updated my config file with the saucelabs specific properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to remove the sauceSeleniumAddress property from the config file.  Once I did that my tests started running in Saucelabs.